# Proper Way To Read and Replace Password Strings

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a bash script that reads in user input to auto install Wordpress.

I have two issues: sed command to replace password string in wp-config file,
update user password that user inputs.

sed command works for my first two string replacements but for a random password string it does not. Is there a specific way to read it in so it can take any string value? I've tried replacing '/' with '%'.

For the mysql query I can tell it updates and hashes it, but it doesn't work for my user login when I try it. For the mysql command I am already logged in under the root login and don't need to put in user and password credentials to run the query.

Here is my bash code snippets:

Sed code snippet:

```
sed -i  's/'"$defaultpass"'/'"$dbPass"'/g'  /home/"$newuser"/public_html/wp-config.php || \
    { echo'couldnt update db password in wpconfig file'; exit 1; }
```

Password Update MySql Query:

```
mysql> use "$fulldb" << EOF
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('"$wrdpressPass"') where id=2 LIMIT 1;  
EOF
```

Comment: What do you mean it "does not work"? What is the problem? Is it that the password contains /and that conflicts with the seed command `s///`? If that's the case, change the separator to something that cannot occur in the password.

Comment: it will wrap around the password text that it finds, is it valid to put "|" ?

Comment: the "|" sed seperators fixed my issue with updating the password in the wp-config file. it seems like my mysql password update is still incorrect.